# unterminated `s' command in sed

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

The command below is being used in a simple **bash script** to get the temporary password in MySQL 5.7.

```
vzctl exec $VEID 'defaultpass=$(cat /var/log/mysqld.log | grep "A temporary password is generated for" | tail -1 | sed -n 's/.*root@localhost: //p')'
```

However it says the following when I run the command for testing:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unterminated `s' command
```

Can someone please explain me what I am doing wrong exactly. I am by no means an expert, but I thought this would be correct. I also tried replacing ' with ", but that didn't work. No errors then, but $defaultpass returns empty then.

Follow-up: unfortunately when I use double-quotes,as described by pii_ke, the output of the variable is empty / blank. So that's not working. Maybe something else is wrong here?

Comment: Not sure which exactly character causes this, but if you want to NOT quote regex chars you have to use `sed -E`

Comment: why not separate out into multiple commands instead of single complicated command? and no need to use `cat` there.. just do `grep 'string' filename`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the whole third argument to `vzctl` command is quoted with single quotes. You should place `sed` commands inside double quotes:

```
vzctl exec $VEID 'defaultpass=$(cat /var/log/mysqld.log | grep "A temporary password is generated for" | tail -1 | sed -n "s/.*root@localhost: //p")'
```

Comment: Nevermind, I was wrong. The output is empty when I call the variable defaultpass. This is what i meant that I already tried it with double quotes. At first I thought it worked, but I already used the variable before (so it still remembered that input).

So if I use your example; with double quotes and I call the variable the output is blank/empty...?

Comment: Try something like `defaultpass=$(vzctl exec $VEID '…')`. Then it will set `defaultpass` in current scope.